Selecting a white ball from an urn.
If I have four urns. One has 3 black balls, another has 2 white and one black, another has 1 white and 2 black and the last one has 3 white balls.
If I want the probability of selecting a white then each urn has the same chance of being selected so we would obtain:
$$P(W) = \frac{1}{4} \times 0 + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times 1.$$
If I select a white ball, then replace it. I want the probability of choosing a white again.
Because I selected a white and replaced it, the probability of choosing each urn is now different. For instance choosing the urn with 1 white ball is now 1/6, and the probability of choosing the urn with 2 white balls is now 2/6 = 1/3. etc.
That is, the calculation is now
$$P(W) = 0 \times 0 + \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2} \times 1.$$
Is my logic correct?

The rules are not clear.  I gather that, at least at the first stage, we have no idea which urn is which and we choose the urn uniformly at random, right?  But then, at the second stage, you appear to suggest that we no longer choose uniformly at random.  Ok...but then what distribution to we choose from?

Are you saying that you choose the second ball from the same urn you chose initially?

How are you deciding from which urn to draw each ball?

This is an application of conditional probability or Bayes' theorem.
One approach is to say that after seeing the first white, the posterior probabilities of having chosen each bag is $\frac{0}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{2}{6}, \frac{3}{6}$ respectively.
So if you then choose again from the same bag, the probability of a second white ball is $\frac{0}{3}\times\frac{0}{6} + \frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{6} + \frac{2}{3}\times\frac{2}{6} + \frac{3}{3}\times\frac{3}{6}  =\frac{14}{18}=\frac{7}{9} \approx 0.778$, which is essentially your argument.

See also conditional probability.  As other responses have indicated, you have (essentially) filled the gap in lack of formal training via your intuition.  I regard intuition as a powerful and indispensable weapon in attacking probability problems.  However, I also advocate formal training, which will often ease the burden that you place on your intuition.
